# Display select group name for group with no nested options in react select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using component [react-select](https://github.com/jedwatson/react-select):

```
    <Select
      options={transformedDataWithSubItems}
      value={selectedItem}
      onChange={handleChange}
      isClearable={isClearable}
      placeholder={placeholder}
    />
```

transformedDataWithSubItems look like this:

```
const transformedDataWithSubItems = [
  { id: 1, label: "1", options: [{ label: 'sub', value: 'sub' }, { label: 'sub', value: 'sub' }] },
  { id: 3, label: "2", options: [{ label: 'sub', value: 'sub' }, { label: 'sub', value: 'sub' }] },
  { id: 5, label: "3", options: [] }
];
```

Some categories have no items(label 3). The select component is not displaying categories like this, how could I fix this? I need to display the category name without elements.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgWIT.png)

Comment: "*The select component is not displaying categories like this...*" - what select component, you haven't shown us one. How is displaying the rest of the categories? What code have you tried? Where is your "*[mcve]*" code that we can see in order to *try* to help? We know nothing about what you're doing except for the information you've put into your question which, as yet, isn't enough to allow us to offer anything resembling help.

Comment: I agree, added a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no nested options, then you need to remove the `options` property.

Change `{ id: 5, label: "3", options: [] }` => `{ id: 5, label: "3" }`

```
const transformedDataWithSubItems = [
      { id: 1, label: "1", options: [{ label: 'sub', value: 'sub' }, { label: 'sub', value: 'sub' }] },
      { id: 3, label: "2", options: [{ label: 'sub', value: 'sub' }, { label: 'sub', value: 'sub' }] },
      { id: 5, label: "3", options: [] }
    ].map(category => {
      if (category.options.length === 0) return {id: category.id, label: category.label};
      return category;
    });
```

**Edit:**
If you want to have it displayed as category, then you must have at least one element inside options. So add one element inside options and disable it. To do that

1. Add `{ label: 'No sub category', disabled: true }`

```
const transformedDataWithSubItems = [
 {
   id: 1,
   label: '1',
   options: [
     { label: 'sub', value: 'sub' },
     { label: 'sub', value: 'sub' },
   ],
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   label: '2',
   options: [
     { label: 'sub', value: 'sub' },
     { label: 'sub', value: 'sub' },
   ],
 },
 { id: 5, label: '3', options: [] },
].map((category) => {
 if (category.options.length === 0) {
   return { ...category, options: [{ label: 'No sub category', disabled: true }]};
 }
 return category;
});
```

2. Add `isOptionDisabled` props to select component.

   ```
    <Select
      options={transformedDataWithSubItems}
      value={selectedItem}
      onChange={handleChange}
      isClearable={isClearable}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      isOptionDisabled={(option) => option.disabled}
    />
   ```

See [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-forked-f0ivx?file=/index.js)

Comment: i tried this. If there is no options, then it is displayed as a regular element, but not as a category name

Comment: if you want  to display it as category then use edited approach.